# "Invalid fetch-style given for caching result" when using Redis caching with Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I get an "Invalid fetch-style given for caching result" whenever I use:

```
$query->useResultCache(true);
```

with Doctrine 2 and by setting in the query:

```
$query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I'm able to cache the results when I don't use hydration and return the results as so:

```
$query->getResult();
```

I use Doctrine 2, Zend 2 and PHP 5.5